# New data is not getting created if it is not present on the autocomplete dropdown on rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I am trying to implement jquery autocomplete on a field in rails app. I am following Railscasts video. I have successfully implemented the autocomplete feature. But I am also trying to add new data if it is not present on the autocomplete dropdown. I spent a lot of time on this but not able to overcome this issue. Following is my code:

**equipment.rb**

```
def manufacturer_name
    manufacturer.try(:name)
end

def manufacturer_name=(name)
    self.manufacturer = Manufacturer.find_or_create_by(:name => params[:other][:manufacturer_name], :status => 1)
end
```

**js**

```
$('#equipment_manufacturer_name').autocomplete({
    source: function(req, res) {
    var arraySource = $('#equipment_manufacturer_name').data('autocomplete-source');
    var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(arraySource, req.term);
    res(results.slice(0, 10));
    }
});
```

**html.erb** field

```
<label for="select">Manufacturer * :</label>
<%= f.text_field :manufacturer_name, data: {autocomplete_source: Manufacturer.order(:name).map(&:name)} %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan to add data you can use `source` block with `ajax` request or if you want to use existing data you can `select` block.Like this:

```
$('#equipment_manufacturer_name').autocomplete({
    minLength: 1,
    source: function(req, res) {
      var arraySource = $('#equipment_manufacturer_name').data('autocomplete-source');
      var results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(arraySource, req.term);
      res(results.slice(0, 10));
    },
    response: function(event, ui) {
      // ui.content is the array that's about to be sent to the response callback.
      if (ui.content.length == 0) {
        $.ajax({
          url : "/set_manufacturer",
          data: {name: $(this).val()}, 
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){

          }
        });  
      }
    },

    select: function(event, ui){
      console.log(ui);
    } 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding new data using ajax then you have to reload or refresh the autocomplete data.
One more thing it might be adding in the autocomplete list but you mentioned slice(0, 10), check whether this might causing the issue.

Comment: I checked it is not adding to the database itself.

Comment: I think I am missing the ajax function itself. I just followed that video and no where he mentioned about writing ajax to add it to db. Could you please tell me how can I add this using ajax? @Shaik

Comment: There is callback 'select' in autocomplete, after select send ajax request to the controller and create new data. Then refresh autocomplete data and select the new data.